# GraphQL code generator - typescript-graphql-request generates sdk with invalid import

Tags: typescript, graphql, graphql-codegen

I'm trying to use [typescript-graphql-request](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/plugins/typescript/typescript-graphql-request) to generate an sdk.
The generated file contains this import at the top

```
import * as Dom from 'graphql-request/dist/types.dom';
```

You can see an example if you go [here](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen) and select "graphql-request typed SDK" in the select

This throws an error when I try to build my application

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'graphql-request/dist/types.dom' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

I have added graphql-request, but there is no /dist. vscode is giving me following suggestions:
[image]

So my question is why does it try to import from /dist/types.dom? Why isn't it importing from 'graphql-request'. Am I supposed to build the graphql-request in node_modules first somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Found this issue on gh](https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator/issues/9046)

Seems to be a problem with graphql-request 5.2.0, pinning it to 5.1.0 fixes the problem

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that with `graphql-request 5.2.0` you have to import from `*/src/types.dom` and no more from `*/dist/types.dom`.

Add this line to your codegen.ts file to edit the file after each generation :

```
hooks: {
        afterOneFileWrite: [
          'sed -i -e"s|graphql-request/dist/types\.dom|graphql-request/src/types.dom|g"'
        ]
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers above worked locally but I kept getting an error on netlify builds.

So I added the [add](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/plugins/other/add) plugin, to add a `// @ts-nocheck` comment to the generated file.

```
// codegen.ts
import { CodegenConfig } from '@graphql-codegen/cli';

const config: CodegenConfig = {
  overwrite: true,
  schema: 'github-schema-loader.js',
  documents: ['./src/**/*.query.ts', './src/**/*.mutation.ts'],
  generates: {
    'src/lib/github.ts': {
      plugins: [
        'typescript',
        'typescript-operations',
        'typescript-react-query',
        {
          add: {
            content: '// @ts-nocheck',
          },
        },
      ],
      config: {
        fetcher: 'graphql-request',
      },
    },
  },
};
export default config;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as explained above by [Benjamin Fourgeaud](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75898859/11234985) (only my version is graphql-request 6.1.0), but you can first try to re-run your codegen. It has fixed it for me without the need to add a hook to edit the file. In my case the new version of the codegen plugin imports from the correct place.